# Memory-safe file-reading in C

Tags: c, strings, memory-management, file

I am trying to write a single function that will read a certain number of bytes from a C file, or the entire file, based on the arguments. I want it to be memory-safe of course, and deal with `NULL` terminators and the like. Not only that, but it should be efficient.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *read(FILE *file, long bytes) {
    /* This function takes a FILE pointer <file> and reads <bytes> bytes from it. These
     * bytes are returned as a char* back to the calling function and should be freed
     * since they were malloc'd. This function was an attempt to recreate the
     * .read( [bytes] ) method on python file objects */

    /**********************************
     Set bytes to 0 to read entire file
     **********************************/

    long fileSize = 0; // File size to zero before byte check

    if (bytes == 0) {
        fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END); // seek to end
        fileSize = ftell(file); // find size of file by checking end
        rewind(file); // back to the beginning for reading
    } else {
        fileSize = ++bytes; // extra byte for NULL 
    }

    char buffer[16]; // We will read the file 16 bytes at a time
    char *file_out = malloc(fileSize + 1);
    if (file_out == NULL) {
         fputs("Could not allocate enough memory", stderr);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, 16, file) != NULL) {
        strncat(file_out, buffer, 16);
    }

    return file_out;
}
```

Is this efficient enough for large files and fringe cases?

Comment: Why reading in chunks of 16 bytes, if you already allocated the memory for the whole file size? You just could read it in in one go using `fread()`.

Comment: Because I don't actually know what I'm doing but that's a good suggestion I see what you mean

Comment: Tangential warning: It is very likely that your C library already has a function named `read`; if it does, it is a *lower-level* operation than `fread`.  Because this function is widely known and used, naming your function `read` is likely to confuse people who need to read your code in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, you're allocating memory using `malloc` inside your function. This forces the caller to use `free` to delete the memory block when the caller may want to use a different allocator for memory management. I'd recommend changing your function's signature like this:

```
size_t read(FILE *file, long bytes, char *buffer, int bufferSize) { ... }
```

where `buffer` is the pointer to the target buffer and `bufferSize` is the number of bytes in that buffer.

This way you don't have to deal with allocating the block that you use to read into - the caller can fully manage it, using any memory-management functions. This frees up your return type from being a pointer (since the caller already knows where data will go) and now you can easily return number of bytes read or `-1` on error.

Comment: YES that's what I was looking for I couldn't think of it. Thank you

Comment: I've gone and done some things does this look better.

Comment: Why have two arguments `bytes` and `bufferSize`? You will eventually read *at most `bytes` and at most `bufferSize` bytes*, you might just collapse both into one.

Comment: @Darkhogg if `bytes` is set to `0` (to read entire file) the caller needs to allocate enough bytes (without knowing the file size ahead of time) and the function needs to be able to verify that the allocated buffer is big enough to hold all data. If the buffer is too small, the function can return an error code that says so.

Comment: This would leave the function as nothing but an inefficient wrapper around `fread(3)` and require the caller to do half of the work before each call.  Returning allocated memory is idiomatic C; just be sure the function's documentation points out that this is happening.

Comment: @Blrfl You're right, I wouldn't write a function like this myself but - whether it's idiomatic or not - returning allocated memory from a function is something I wouldn't do unless the function is an allocator. It just introduces too many problems in larger software.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of `fgets`, you can use `fread` to read directly into the `file_out`:

```
int totalRead = 0;
int size;
while( fileSize > total_read && (size = fread(file_out + totalRead, 1, fileSize - totalRead, file) != 0) {
    totalRead+=size;
}
if(totalRead < fileSize){
    //couldn't read entire file
}
file_out[total_read] = '\0';

return file_out;
```

This avoids the \$O(n^2)\$ complexity of doing `strncat` on a growing string.

Doing an exit from within a helper function is not recommended because the calling code cannot recover from it. Instead, return a special value that specifies something went wrong.

Also, make up your mind about the naming convention of camelCase vs. snake_case.

Comment: This solves the biggest problem with the original code and ought to be the accepted answer. Using `fgets` when you want to read arbitrary binary data is absurd.

Answer (score 8):

If you'll be following the [C way of doing things with `read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read), then you should probably have it return the number of bytes successfully read, preferably of type [`ssize_t`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Primitives.html).  This would allow `-1` to be returned if the read failed.  It may also be useful to have it set [`errno`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) accordingly, which would allow the user to print an appropriate error message via [`perror()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror).

The user may expect the function to return something instead of just having the program (specifically the current process) exit.  It may work for *you*, but it could still be a burden for others who are using it.

Comment: How do I get the text to update if I don't return though

Comment: @Tom: Same thing that that linked function does: pass the buffer as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, your function is not really ok - it's not efficient, and there's a few flaws. It's not *bad*, but could do with some, uh... finishing touches.

You don't check the `<file>` variable for being `NULL` on entry.  I personally like to ensure anything coming in is sanity-checked before use.  Somewhat akin to Eiffel's "Preconditions".

If the `malloc()` fails the function just exits the whole executable.  It would be better to just return `NULL`.  It should be up to the core-body of the programme to decide on low-memory handling.

Ratchet Freak's post above covers the major problem with the `strncat()` and \$O(N^2)\$ time requirements.  I want to stress that this is really important - what he means is you have to re-process everything already read each time the next block of bytes is added to the end.  Without significantly modifying your function, maintaining a pointer to the end of the string would be enough to fix this issue.  For small files, this re-processing makes no significant difference - but what about when that file is 30 gigabytes.

Minor issues:

- You're reading a tiny amount of the file at once - 16 bytes.  Why not 512 bytes? 8k? etc.
- You allocate +1 bytes (presumably for the `\0`), twice.  (What if the caller is reading a binary file?)
- If the caller asks to read 500 bytes from the file, but it only has 5 bytes, the function still allocates 501 bytes.
- What happens when the size of the file is more than the size of a signed long? Using `unsigned long` helps (and you can't have a negatively-sized file).
- There is no way of signalling an I/O error.  But for a function like this, a success OR failure is not too bad.

What you are trying to achieve with the file-reading loop in this function is already covered by the C function `fread()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * Read <bytes> of data from the given file, or the entire
 * content if <bytes> is zero.  Returns a pointer to a zero-terminated
 * string on success, NULL otherwise.
 */
char *gulpFile(FILE *file, unsigned long bytes) 
{
    char *file_out = NULL;
    unsigned long file_size = 0; // File size to zero before byte check

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        // We need to know the size of the file
        fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END); 
        file_size = ftell(file); 
        rewind(file); 

        if (bytes == 0)
        {
            file_size = bytes; 
        }
        else if (bytes < file_size)
        {
            file_size = bytes;
        }

        file_out = (char *)malloc(1 + file_size);
        if (file_out != NULL)
        {
            file_out[file_size] = '\0'; // terminated.

            size_t bytes_read = fread(file_out, 1, file_size, file);
            if (bytes_read != file_size)
            {
                // Some kind of I/O error 
                free(file_out);
                file_out = NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    return file_out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code need not work, per [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

```
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END); // seek to end
    fileSize = ftell(file); // find size of file by checking end
    rewind(file); // back to the beginning for reading
```

Per **7.21.9.2 The `fseek` function**:

> A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a
>   `whence` value of `SEEK_END`.

`fseek()` to `SEEK_END` on a binary stream isn't guaranteed to work.

And, per **7.21.9.4 The `ftell` function**:

> For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified
>   information, usable by the `fseek` function for returning the file
>   position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the
>   `ftell` call; the difference between two such return values is not
>   necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written
>   or read.

`ftell()` on a text stream doesn't return the number of characters you need to read.

So `fseek( ..., SEEK_END );` on a binary stream isn't guaranteed to work, and `ftell()` on a text stream doesn't tell you how many bytes you need to read.

Any claims to the contrary usually rely on POSIX-specified behavior, which means you can measure the size of a file directly using one of the POSIX-specified `stat` family of library calls.

Also, the `fseek()` call will discard any buffered data that the calling code might have written to the file, and will also modify the current file position.  Something like this will do what you want per your question, without such side effects (note the use of an integral file descriptor instead of a `FILE *` - you can get the file descriptor to the underlying file for a `FILE *` using [`fileno( FILE * )`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html)):

```
char *readEntireFile( int fd )
{
    struct stat sb;
    int rc = fstat( fd, &sb );
    if ( rc < 0 )
    {
        return( NULL );
    }

    // use calloc() so the virtual pages are created before
    // trying to put data into them (really fast devices can
    // deliver data faster than VM managers might be able to
    // create virtual pages and map them to physical RAM)
    //
    // and calloc() NUL-terminates the data...
    char *data = calloc( 1, sb.st_size + 1 );
    if ( data == NULL )
    {
        return( NULL );
    }

    // use pread() so we don't need to know nor change the
    // current offset
    ssize_t bytes_read = pread( fd, data, sb.st_size, ( off_t ) 0 );
    // error checking here

    return( data );
}
```

As others have noted, don't call your function [`read()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html).  That name is already used.

I've also made no effort to address the issues others have raised about conveying the number of bytes actually read.